# firebase storage doesn't store image file

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to store image files in firebase storage and then update my cover photo and profile photo with that images. I wrote all the code correctly but the code is working only for cover image and not for profile image. I mean i can update my cover photo but profile photo is not updating because firebase storage is not saving my profile image, i don't know what is wrong with my code. here is the code.

Java file

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<FriendsModel> list;
    FragmentProfileBinding binding;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    FirebaseDatabase database;


    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        // step 2 set image on cover photo in app

        database.getReference().child("Users").child(auth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    Picasso.get().load(user.getCoverPhoto()).placeholder(R.drawable.coverphoto_placeholder)
                            .into(binding.coverImage);
                    Picasso.get().load(user.getProfile()).placeholder(R.drawable.coverphoto_placeholder)
                            .into(binding.profilePicture);
                    binding.userName.setText(user.getName());
                    binding.profession.setText(user.getProfession());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new FriendsModel(R.drawable.profile2));
        list.add(new FriendsModel(R.drawable.profile3));
        list.add(new FriendsModel(R.drawable.profile4));
        list.add(new FriendsModel(R.drawable.profile2));
        list.add(new FriendsModel(R.drawable.profile3));


        FriendsAdapter adapter = new FriendsAdapter(list, getContext());


        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        binding.friendsRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.friendsRV.setAdapter(adapter);


        binding.changeCoverPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // this will open gallery
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 11);

            }
        });

        binding.verified.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // this will open gallery
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 22);
            }
        });
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 11) {
            if (data.getData() != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                binding.coverImage.setImageURI(uri);

                // to store images in Firebase storage

                final StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("cover_photo")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
                reference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "cover photo saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // step 1 to set image on cover photo. For step 2 goto onCreate()

                        reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                database.getReference().child("Users").child(auth.getUid()).child("coverPhoto")
                                        .setValue(uri.toString());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if (data.getData() != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    binding.profilePicture.setImageURI(uri);

                    // to store images in Firebase storage

                    final StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("profile_photo")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
                    reference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "profile picture updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            // step 1 to set image on cover photo. For step 2 goto onCreate()

                            reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    database.getReference().child("Users").child(auth.getUid()).child("profile")
                                            .setValue(uri.toString());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what the difference is between a profile picture and a cover image? An image is an image i would think.

Comment: Did you already attach an `onFailure` handler to the uploads, to see if you get an error that indicates why the upload fails?

Comment: My app has a profile fragment in which there are two portion one is cover photo and one is profile photo. The code works fine for cover photo but not for profile photo.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a Failure listener to see if something goes wrong?